# json_decode returns syntax error with a valid json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode the following json which I have checked with jsonlint and returns that it is a valid json:

> [{"gatewayId": "5154979870408704", "sensorId": "5698497110081536"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T225959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB1", "io": "in"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T235959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB2", "io": "out"}]

However the result is always Syntax Error when I call json_last_error_msg()
Here is my code:

```
$param = substr($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, 1);
$param =utf8_encode($param);
$json = json_decode($param,true);
echo json_last_error_msg();
var_dump($param);
```

The json is being sent to me using curl which is why it is in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, and I'm removing the first character because when making a var_dump I noticed a blank character there, however that's not the problem. Any help is appreciated.
**EDIT:**
This is the result of var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)

> string(187) " [{gatewayId: 5154979870408704, sensorId: 5698497110081536}, {timestamp: 20160513T225959000Z, tagId: 123456789AB1, io: in}, {timestamp: 20160513T235959000Z, tagId: 123456789AB2, io: out}]"

**EDIT2:**
So turns out it was because the double quotes were being removed in the curl request that had the payload like

```
-d "[{"gatewayId": "5154979870408704", "sensorId": "5698497110081536"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T225959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB1", "io": "in"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T235959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB2", "io": "out"}]"
```

I replaced the double quotes with single quotes in the begining and end of the payload and now its working fine, just leaving this here in case anyone has the same problem.
new payload:

```
-d '[{"gatewayId": "5154979870408704", "sensorId": "5698497110081536"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T225959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB1", "io": "in"}, {"timestamp": "20160513T235959000Z", "tagId": "123456789AB2", "io": "out"}]'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could not replicate.  [It decoded just fine for me.](https://ideone.com/15bSFE)  Can you [edit] your question to include the result of `var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)`?

Comment: What does the error say, exactly?

Comment: I edited the question to add the var_dump of HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.
@Henders the error is Syntax error that's the only thing I get.

Comment: use trim instead of substr. However, it's working fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0da8f2d0f2ab2b3c7d7eae47d8ba70fe3678b930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `var_dump` I read

```
string(187) " [{gatewayId: 5154979870408704, ...
```

Here the key `gatewayId` is not quoted. The [JSON standard](http://json.org/) requires keys to be strings which use `""`. The data thus is not valid JSON and PHP rejects it.

Comment: Well i feel dumb now, totally didn't notice that. I dont understand why its removing the quotes since in the curl request I send it as I posted in the OP. anyway thanks!

Comment: Same issue with me when I fetch data from database. Any solution which you have implemented?